# Squid proxy server ignoring hosts file :(

Tags: windows-server-2008, squid, hosts, domain-name-system

Using: `Squid Cache version 2.7.STABLE3 for i686-pc-winnt` ...

Whatever I put into the `hosts` file, it seems to be ignoring it.

here's my configuration :-

```
...
hosts_file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
...
```

And yep - i'm restarting squid each time i change (and save) the hosts file and yep, i've 10x checked the `hosts` file is the same as the one listed in the config file.

Does anyone else have this problem? I'm not even sure how i can debug it. Right now, i'm using the command line squid and squidclient to try and see what's going on, but i keep getting `X-Squid-Error: ERR_DNS_FAIL 0`.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use forward slashes (/), rather than backslashes, to separate your path components.

Comment: Perfect :) the example path (in the documentation) has the backslashes :( I just copied that.  **ALSO** .. the last entry in the hosts is not read if u do NOT have a newline after the last entry!!! FFS! So I added a comment to the end of the file `# end of hosts file` to make SURE all the entries get read in. WOW! #fail

Comment: That last little bit (regarding newlines) is a bug; have you reported it?  It might not be a bad idea to also suggest either forking the sample config file per-platform, or adding comments to make it clear the direction of slashes that need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way to start debuging a problem is to look at the available log files. It can be a very good and valuable source of information to help debuging the problems.